# Redirect to Custom page after ADB2C signin/signup - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

How to I redirect to a custom page after signin/signup with ADB2C ?

I want to populate my model and pass it to the new view after signin/signup, but it keeps redirecting to the following: https://localhost:44342/account/signupsignin

Below is my Code:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public void SignUpSignIn()
        {
            // Use the default policy to process the sign up / sign in flow
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge();
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

            }

            string email = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("emails").Value;

            // We do not want to use any existing identity information
            EnsureLoggedOut();

            AccountRegistrationModel ARVM = new AccountRegistrationModel();

            ARVM = CallPersonalDetails(_registrationRepository.GetUserId(email), "English");

            RedirectToAction("Account", "Register_PersonalDetails", ARVM);

            //HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/account/Register_PersonalDetails" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);



            //Response.Redirect("/");
        }
```

I've tried using the part thats commented out as well:

```
//HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/account/Register_PersonalDetails" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

This "Shows" the right URL but displays a page that says its not found. I need to pass the model through as well - How do I

1. Redirect to my own custom page after signin/signup
2. Pass a model to this page as well.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to figure it out.

The Response.Redirect("/") redirects to my Index ActionResult in my Home Controller, so within that ActionResult, I used the RedirectToAction to direct me to the View I wanted(Obviously there is code doing the required checks etc. first)

Maybe this isnt the right way of doing it, but it worked for me.

Thanks.